# ExtJS - editing calendar events

Tags: json, extjs

I'm working on the admin panel of a project using ExtJS, and there I have a Panel, CalendarEvents where data for any upcoming events should be added, deleted and of course, edited if need so.

The problem is that the people who are going to administer this admin panel won't be people with computer education, and when they insert data for a new event or change the data for an existing one, there must be an easy to understand interface to do that.

They must be able to add the time of the event, as well as the date, and it makes it even more difficult, at least for me, to think of a way to provide these functions. Until now, we've been using double click and editing the info manually by writing in the cell, but this is going to bring a lot of problems with the right date/time formatting.

So, I'm looking for a good way to implement this option in my admin panel.

Comment: This seems like a better question for the UX site, not SO.

Comment: Well, dunno, I think it's a common issue to add/edit a date-time column it's just my first time having to do it so I'm asking for a good way to do this. I've been thinking for a dropdown menu but the cell should include the exact time of the event so it's not quite an option.

Comment: I think you're question is a good one, which is why I cleaned it up for you, but I also think it's more about UI/UX design than it is a programming question. What I get from this is that you want to know how to make this easy for your users, which suggests usability/UI design. If that is not correct, please edit your question to make it clear what you're looking for with code examples. SO is more for programming questions as per the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), and the best questions on this site have code examples, things you've tried, research you've done, etc.

Comment: Yes, I try to and I'm putting a code most of the time I post a question here, but it's one of those time when I don't even know where to start from. All of my ideas (not that much though) are complicated once and I don't want to get involved in any of them unless I don't find another solution, and since I think it's probably a common issued i decided to try here. Anyways I understand your point so if you could tell me a site where this question would be me more appropriate I'll be more than happy to post it there.Just SO is always my 1st option.

Comment: @jmort253: Let's let Leron ping me if he wants to move.  No rush.